# Python async and sync functions executed as threads

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I would like to call an async function from a pure sync code.
I would like to execute that async function in the background without stucking my prog.
My idea is to use the threading module.

```
from threading import Thread
import asyncio

async def func1():
    ...

def func2():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=func1).start()
    Thread(target=func2).start()
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python 3.7 there is [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run).

Replace

```
    Thread(target=func1).start()
```

by

```
    Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(func1(),)).start()
```

Comment: I have been searching for this exactly for 3 days :) I tried similar ideas but they didn't work , asyncio.run is the solution , thanks :)